# Apache config file not being installed

Tags: raspbian, apache2.4

I had apache2 installed on my raspberry pi 4 and was getting some strange behavior so I removed it via apt remove apache2, removed the  /etc/apache2 directory and reinstalled by sudo apt-get apache2 -y.

After reinstallation the server would not start, I determine that there was no apache2.conf file in /etc/apache2.

I've tried installing and reinstalling several time to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dpkg --get-selections showed apache2 in  deinstall state, I than ran  dpkg -P apache2 and reinstalled apache apt-get apache2 -y and the install was successful.

Answer (score 2):

try

```sh
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

If you just want a light-weight http server you might want to try Nginx as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).